# How to change the title of a browser page which a servlet streamed a PDF to?

Tags: java, pdf, browser, servlets, titlebar

My Java based webapp has a servlet which streams PDF content back to the browser based on request parameter.

e.g. user clicks on an A tag with an href of "myApp/FetchPDFServlet?id=123". Servlet mapping picks up request, streams PDF data to response as mime-type application/pdf, closes flushes buffers.

However the browser title bar for the page displaying the PDF reads "FetchPDFServlet?id=123"

How can I change the title the browser displays for the page that displays the PDF? 
So the browser title is "Here is the amazing PDF" not "FetchPDFServlet?id=123".

Is it possible at all? How best to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Add this header to your HttpServletResponse:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=Here is the Amazing PDF");
```

I believe the browser will pick it up and use it as the title of the window.

Comment: `ServletResponse response = pageContext.getResponse();`  Why object `responce` doensn't contain the method `setHeader`, when i am trying create my tag with class `jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;`?

Comment: @Taylor use HttpServletResponse

Answer (score 4):

You could display the PDF in an iframe.
Something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Here is the amazing PDF</title>
      <style type="text/css">
       html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
       iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="100%" length="100%" src="myApp/FetchPDFServlet?id=123"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

So instead of linking to a pdf document using `myApp/FetchPDFServlet?id=123`, you would link to something that returns the above html. For example, a jsp page: `myApp/ShowPDF.jsp?id=123&title=Here%20is%20the%20amazing%20PDF`

Answer (score 2):

I have hit this issue,and while my solution has quite a few restrictions I thought I would share it.

Baiscally I will open the pdf in a new tab, and then change its title from the original page.

```
$('#aa').click(function(){
    ref = window.open('resume.pdf','mywindow');     
    ref.onload = function(){
        ref.document.title="New Title";
    }
    return false;
    });
  });
```

Note that the parent and child pages must be in the same domain.

I have tested this in a few browsers, and here are the results:

- Chrome 10 - Works like a treat
- Safari 5 - Works, but by default opens in a new window not tab. User can change this to open all new windows in tabs.
- IE 8 - Doesn't work, as expected :op
- Firefox - Works like a treat

Answer (score 2):

The tab title is taken from the PDF documents metadata, specifically the Title attribute. So if you generate the document in your app, your PDF library should have a way to set the documents metadata.

Comment: I've tried this. It almost worked. The tab-title is now the pdf-title (good) + the request value (bad).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a solution in java and it worked. You can set given headers in other languages

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"MyFile.pdf\"");
response.setContentType("application/pdf; name=\"MyFile.pdf\"");
response.getOutputStream().write(pdfAsBytesArray);
```

Comment: AFAIK [Content-Type header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) doesn't contain a `name` property.

Comment: Not working for me. The tab name is always the name of the request value and not the name of "filename".

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather simple solution to this problem. The main part is here the url mapping with /fileDownload/*

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/fileDownload/*" })
@Slf4j
public class FileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Inject
    private SimpleDocumentStoreService documentService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    {
        String id = req.getParameter("id");

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id))
        {
            try
            {
                documentService.streamDatei(id, resp);
                resp.flushBuffer();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                log.error("error downloading file", e);
            }
       }
   }
```

}

And the caller:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/fileDownload/#{document.name}?id=#{document.id}" target="_blank">
        <h:outputText value="#{document.name}"/>
    </a>
```