# Set browser title in servlet which serves a PDF file

Tags: java, servlets, download, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the title of a browser page which a servlet streamed a PDF to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058959/how-to-change-the-title-of-a-browser-page-which-a-servlet-streamed-a-pdf-to)

I want to display a PDF file in browser, so I send the PDF to response output stream. I set headers:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + getFileName() + "\"");
```

But I have problem with browser title. FireFox display servlet title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058959/how-to-change-the-title-of-a-browser-page-which-a-servlet-streamed-a-pdf-to  same question, may have some useful tips.

Comment: this might also help you http://forums.asp.net/post/4542537.aspx

Comment: To Jon Taylor: I read it, but I don't want to use such things, because when user click Save he saw servlet name.

Answer (score 1):

The request URL as appears in browser's address bar must contain the PDF filename in order to get it to work the way you want. This is easier if you map the PDF servlet on a prefix URL pattern something like as `/pdf/*` instead of a static path something like as `/pdf` so that it can also be invoked on `/pdf/blahblah`, `/pdf/foo.ext` and so on.

E.g.

```html
<a href="pdf/filename.pdf">
```

in combination with

```
@WebServlet("/pdf/*")
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(...) {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1); // filename.pdf
        // ...
    }

}
```

Additional advantage is that the *Save As* filename in IE browser will also be fixed. That browser namely extracts it from the last path of the request URL instead of from the content disposition header.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to set the title for generated `HTML` Page :-

Try This :

```
out.println("  <HEAD><TITLE>Your Title for browser</TITLE></HEAD>");
```

Use this in `servlet`. Then `servlet` will generate the dynamic page, the above code will add the title to page.

Comment: The OP is about generating PDF files

Comment: @Jasper: OP = original poster; the questioner in person; Heniek in this question. You perhaps meant to say "question" instead of "OP" :)

Comment: That's what I was trying to say.. the OP's question ;-) But you got the point. Thanks for pointing this out.